# Why do I lose trace of the submit button when I post a form with a file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, post

I have a form in my rails app which posts a (invoice) number, amount, date and file to a controller.  I have a `submit` button with a `name` attribute, let's say `"submit"`.

If I post the form without the `file_field`, the params in the controller contain a key `"submit"`, but when I include the `file_field` it disappears.

I'm not intercepting the form submission in any way.  What could be going on here?

Edit - Basically the form looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'controller', :action => :update}, {:remote => true, :multipart => true}) do |form| %>

    <%= form.text_field(:date) %>
    <%= form.text_field(:amount) %>
    <%= form.text_field(:number) %>
    <%= form.file_field(:file_upload) %>

    <%= form.submit 'Save', :name => "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Please share the form code.

Comment: Is the form set to multipart?

Comment: form is set to multipart, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  It so happens that I have code to disable submit buttons during a post.  When the file_field is included in the post params the form processing takes longer and by the time the form is actually processing the `submit` button it has been disabled.  I'll have to find a different solution for this.

```
$body.on('submit', 'form[data-remote="true"] ', function() {
    var $railsUjsForm = $(this);
    $railsUjsForm.find('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
});
```